# How can I make Eclipse download new software from a different mirror?

Tags: eclipse

I want to install C/C++ Development Tools, but the mirror Eclipse tries to pull it from just hangs. How can I force it to try another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download the archived repository for the C/C++ development tools in just one zip file from here: [Download cdt-master-8.1.0.zip repository](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/cdt/releases/juno/r/cdt-master-8.1.0.zip)  On the page you can select an appropriate mirror.  Then in your local Eclipse (vanilla install) go to Help > Install software... > Add... > Use the Archive option and point to the downloaded zip file.